# Change cursor by hovering

Tags: css, angular

I like to get a pointer cursor if I hover over a HTML-element.

```
<span #x (mouseover)="x.style.cursor = 'pointer'">HELLO</span>
```

This is working.

But I think if I can make is a bit simpler WITHOUT using a CSS-class (only local style is possible).

Do I need the #x to address the element? Is there a way I can address the element without naming it (e.g. like a "this")??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't realy know what you want but this

```html
<span style="cursor: pointer">HELLO</span>
```

is a bit easyer

Comment: Thanks for removing the tomatoes from my eyes.